# how to display image from my Computer on android emulator?

Tags: android

i wanna display image saved on the D://foldername//foldername//filename from my computer on the android emulator using eclipse and also how to display it from a server? 
as i am accessing the data from the server and also the images are saved on the server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990696/how-to-make-android-emulator-access-my-pc-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're running a web server which provides public access to the image, I don't think you can display an image from your computer using a path like that. You either need to include the image in the `assets` or `res/drawable` folders within the app, or have the image accessible through a web server which you can load from within the app using the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038532/android-how-to-display-and-image-from-url?rq=1).

Comment: i already have web service to get the data from the DB on server

Comment: You should be able to display it either using the link I mentioned in my answer or, if you want to use the `ImageView` widget, by using the method described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for the dummy question , i am brand new in android :)

Comment: No problem, Android is pretty complicated at first :) Glad I could help.